# Connector NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode()Z

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, fips

I am running Confluent Platform version 7.1.0 and my Kafka Connector requires bouncy castle fips library to be present in plugin path so that it can decrypt the encrypted private key.

The `BouncyCastleFipsProvider` is needed at runtime to generate a PrivateKey from encryptedPrivateKey

I get below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode()Z
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvSecureHash$MD5.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.EncryptionUtils.parseEncryptedPrivateKey(EncryptionUtils.java:30)
```

Although, this works fine for confluent 5.5.0 but somehow doesn't work with confluent 6.2.0 or 7.1.0

I have made sure the fips library is present in
`/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins` as well as

```
ls confluent-7.1.0/share/java/kafka/ | grep fips
bc-fips-1.0.2.1.jar
bcpkix-fips-1.0.3.jar
```

I fail to understand the what could be the root cause. When Kafka Connect starts, I see it is loading both the jars from plugin path. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878176/bouncy-castle-nosuchmethoderror-org-bouncycastle-asn1-asn1integer) answer but doesnt apply in this case. The function is [present](https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bc-fips/1.0.2.1/org/bouncycastle/crypto/CryptoServicesRegistrar.html) in bc-fips `bc-fips-1.0.2.1.jar`

Comment: You should not modify the Kafka classpath to fix your Connector plugins. Use an external `plugin.path`, appropriately

Comment: Did you check your `CLASSPATH` and see if there is a version override for that lib?

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer my plugin.path =`/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins` which has the fips library too

Comment: @JavaTechnical I checked KC log file where it was able to load this jar.

Answer (score 0):

The FIPS library is not a "Connect plugin", so despite it "seeing" the JAR, nothing will "load" from it.

You'll need to explicitly set `CLASSPATH=confluent-7.1.0/share/java/kafka/*.jar` environment variable for the JVM to load all the classes from those JARs.

You will also want to use `jar tf`  to actually check content of those JARs for the class in the error.